# Cannot access my web server

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, web-hosting, nameserver

I just subscribed for shared hosting plan on ASPHOSTCENTRAL. I changed my Domain settings and pointed to the name servers as they said(10hrs ago). Since then I've been trying to access my website's default page but I can't. It prompts me to enter a User name and a password.

When I asked the help desk, they said it's working on their end and they can see the default web page.

This is an ASP .Net web application (3.5 framework) with Crystal reports (V12) and MS SQL server database.

The support team said when I try to ping ebolamedia.ae(my domain) then I should get 208.43.160.193 but on my end I see   174.37.255.233.

I don't understand what is wrong. Can someone help me...
I can't access my FTP too.

Comment: Change the DNS settings on your local machine to use Google (8.8.8.8) or something else. If that works, then something is cached or broken on the DNS server you were pointing at.

Comment: Dear Zoredache, Thank you for the response. Can you please specify how to change that setting because I am new to this.

Comment: Not to be rude but if you don't know how to change your local machine's DNS settings you should consider getting a consultant and/or your support team involved. ServerFault probably isn't the right place for this question. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: If you meant to say DNS settings under adapter settings then I know and I already tried that but still it didn't work. I also edited my host file but no luck. I restarted my PC,every switch and router in my home network but nothing helped. I guess it's been 18 hrs since I changed my name server settings.

Comment: It resolves fine from  here... so for what it is worth the rest of the world can see your site. If I do a look up using Google's DNS (8.8.8.8) it works too - I'm not sure why Google's DNS doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks Kce. I don't know what else to try I'm thinking to switch my name server settings under my domain to something else for a while and then reassign to their name server again.

Comment: http://www.dnsvalidation.com/reports/4ed8e8327d79ee236000000a#ns

Answer (score 2):

DNS changes can take some time to propagate everywhere, especially if the hostname you're trying to access has been cached by your DNS resolver and hasn't aged out yet. *Give it time*. The Time-To-Live setting on that record is 24 hours, so it could be up to a day before it resolves correctly for you.

For clients that haven't resolved that domain before, they will get the new settings since there isn't anything cached to get in the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response sysadmin. I have tried clearing my browser cache, system DNS cache, restarted my PC and every network device I have at home. But still it is taking me somewhere else. I asked some of my friends who lives in my area but still no difference. Maybe  it is cached by my ISP because we have only one ISP in our country. Is it possible if it could be cached by my ISP ?

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSaini That is almost definitely your problem.

Comment: http://www.dnsvalidation.com/reports/4ed8e8327d79ee236000000a#ns

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSaini The issues highlighted in the report are things to take up with your hosting provider.

Comment: It's working now! The problem was caused by my ISP cache

Answer (score 0):

I can see your site point to right IP address, 208.43.160.193. I think it is caused by your cache. To make sure, you can try it from another PC. Good luck